# Google Cloud Functions version >= 1 check if node value has changed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I check if a specific node changed?

In version <= v0.9.1 was:

```
event.data.child("chatid").changed()
```

I can't find any documentation on this. I am following this [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/9ce5109babd4f3b240d097debdc570dbe7383682/email-confirmation/functions/index.js#L38):

```
change.after.changed('subscribedToMailingList')
```

and getting the error in the console :

> change.after.changed is not a function

```
exports.ObserveProposals = functions.database.ref("/proposals/{jobid}/{talentid}").onWrite((change, context) => {
      const jID = context.params.jobid;
      const tID = context.params.talentid;
      let jR = admin.database().ref(`/jobs/${jID}`);
      const promises = [];
      if (change.after.exists() && change.after.changed('chatid') && change.after.child("chatid").val()) return null;
      ...
```

The error occurs in the if statement

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that is not working the way you expect (not just one line of it).

Comment: Have you tried comparing 'before' and 'after'?

change.after.val().subscribedToMailingList != change.before.val().subscribedToMailingList

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @AarónBC. I prefer to use the changed method

Comment: Well, looking at the migration guide for v1, it seems that the object type has changed from DeltaSnapshot to DataSnapshot. DeltaSnapshot was the type that had the changed() method. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#changes_by_trigger_type

Comment: Are you confirming the only way to monitor changed values of a node in version >=1 is by comparing change.after.val().subscribedToMailingList != change.before.val().subscribedToMailingList ? I am confused because in the example I am referring above they are using change.after.changed('subscribedToMailingList')

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not confirming that, i understand is confusing because of that code sample (i'm confused about it too), but according to the docs that sample shouldn't work since 'change.after' is now a 'DataSnapshot' and DataSnapshot doesn't have the 'changed' method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Functions [documentation for database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) says:

> For `onWrite` or `onUpdate` events, the first parameter is a `Change` object that contains two snapshots that represent the data state before and after the triggering event.

If you look up the [definition for the `Change` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change), it has:

> The Functions interface for events that change state, such as Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore onWrite and onUpdate.
>
> **Properties**
>
> `after` `non-null Object`
>
> Represents the state after the event.
>
> `before` `non-null Object`
>
> Represents the state prior to the event.

Neither of these has a method similar to the `changed()` of before. So you'll indeed have to do you own comparison between the `before` and `after` data to see what has changed.